# Login Screen+Table View in a Tab Controller= Nothing showing up after initial Login

Tags: iphone, sdk, authentication, tableview, reload

This one's a little complicated~

Got a Login page that validates a username/password from an offsite server.  The server returns a User ID which is then used in my app to find a matching plist file. If there isn't already one, it's supposed to create a new plist for that user with sample data. This all works, but nothing shows up unless I terminate then restart the app.

I think the problem is that the tableview loads simultaneously with the modal login page.

Below is code from my Login Page:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
[fIndicator stopAnimating];
    //convert data from server to a string
NSString *xmlReturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //notify user if username/pass failed
if ([xmlReturn isEqualToString:@"0"] ||[xmlReturn isEqualToString:@"No"] ) {
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login Fail" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Retry" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
    //if server authenticates username/pass
else {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            //set user ID from server into Defaults for app use
    [defaults setObject:xmlReturn forKey:@"AppPref_UI"];
    [defaults synchronize];
            //this is where I think the tableview needs to be told to reload
            //but no idea how to reference that view controller from
            //this modal view controller
    [??? reloadData];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
[xmlReturn release];
```

}

Comment: it would help with a little bit more information about your view hierarchy..

Comment: The main part of the app uses a tab view controller with 2 views: (A) a Nav Controller with a tableview that drills down to detailed view and (B) a simple view showing user info.  The Login Page is called up modally from the Nav Controller if the user is logging in for the first time or has logged out from the app.

Comment: Okay, solved and feeling not-so-smart. If anyone else happens to run into this exact same problem, here's my solution: Replace "[??? reloadData];" with (your function or code for creating a new plist file). My function was "[script aCheckforSavedScripts];" which isn't going to make sense without seeing the whole class and functions I've built for that, but it should give you an idea of what direction to be going.  Anyways, if the new plist is generated here, the tableview will automatically be updated when the login modal view disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the delegate design pattern. The login dialog would tell its delegate when it's done.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <YourProtocol> delegate;
```

and

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(loginCompleted:)]) {
    [self.delegate loginCompleted:self];
}
```

You'd set the delegate when you create the login view controller and present it to the user.